# Regular expressions - After number minimum of two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I detect if a string has a number and after number minimum two characters?
I have a function like this:

```
function checkString(string){
   return !!string.match(/^ (?=.*?[A-Z]) (?=.*?[0-9]) .{8,} /);
}
```

```
asdFghjk    - false,   
asd3fGhjk   - true,  
123aSdfghjk - false,  
asd6H       - false
```

Comment: This regex has nothing to do with your task. `[0-9]` = number, `..` - two chars

Comment: Why should `123aSdfghjk` return false?

Comment: I want after number have min two not number characters

Comment: `[^0-9]` that detects things that are not numbers